# Having trouble communicating between meteor server and meteor App (IONIC)

Tags: android, meteor, ionic-framework

I've created an app with meteor server, and meteor-ionic designed to be the client side. When running "meteor" locally, I can use the browser and everything is functioning properly. Now  I want to move forward - meaning deploy the server side on a production server, and packaging the App to an android APK.
What I tried doing is on the server running meteor (which seems Ok cause I can access via browser), and running the app using:
meteor run android-device --server=http://1.2.3.4:3000   (which is the IP of my server).
The App seems to run fine, but no communication is reaching the server.
I checked network connectivity - which is good, and I do not see any errors on my console.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to debug this further / has managed to make a scenario like mine work ?